# how to use console/windows app without focus on it?

Tags: c#, console-application, keylogger, windows

im going to create a KEylog application that enables me to write all data typed(keys pressed) on a text file/database how can i do this without focus on the windows app/console app?

for a reason , for all you to know, this is for my PC and im not trying to hack an account.
just for me to know what they are doing on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Find an example written in .NET here:

[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)

> This class allows you to tap keyboard and mouse and/or to detect their
>   activity even when an application runs in the background or does not
>   have any user interface at all.

Comment: hmm what is that anyways? any brief summary?

Comment: no because you are a bad boy who wants to spy users and sniff their passwords :-PPP