# C# console get key stroke

Tags: c#, .net, console, keystroke, keylogger

Is there anyway for a C# console application to capture keystroke, including those that are pressed outside of the program, similar to a key logger? The one I found and tried is Console.ReadKey() but it can only read the keystroke sent to the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283397/how-to-use-console-windows-app-without-focus-on-it

Comment: From his followup questions, I think this is more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177856/how-do-i-trap-ctrl-c-in-a-c-sharp-console-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a low level keyboard hook. Here is an example using windows forms, but you can easily apply the same concept to a console application:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can it help me capture key combination, like Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Alt + Delete?

Comment: Unfortunately to handle Ctrl + Alt + Delete you have to write your own GINA implementation in C or C++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have something else to ask though: How can I make it so that if the user holds down a certain button for a while, instead of showing that button many times in a row (like "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") it will only show once (show "A" only once).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to handle global keyboard events. Have a look at [A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Windows API, I'd [check GetAsyncKeyState](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html).

Answer (score -1):

yes...you'll need to look at system keyboard hooks...I think this post has what you need:

[Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Can it help me capture key combination, like Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Alt + Delete?